# Azure Functions v2 Python - CosmosDB input decorator

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to write a very basic function in an azure function app using the python v2 programming model. All I want it to do is connect to a CosmosDB account and return all the documents listed in a given container called 'systems'. It'll return a filtered set of them in the future but for now there's only one document in it so no filtering required.

This is the function at present based on adapting [these examples from azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-python):

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import json

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.function_name(name="system")
@app.route(route="system")
@app.cosmos_db_input(arg_name="documents", 
                     database_name="database",
                     container_name="systems",
                     connection_string_setting="DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING")
def system(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(documents),
        status_code=200
    )
```

When i try and run the function using the Azure Function Core Tools
(Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.21.1.20667

I get the below error, I cannot for the life of me figure out what information i need to give it for the 'connection' argument. Based on all the azure demos I should only need to provide the connection string which is available in the local.settings.json file with the name DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING.

```
[2023-10-02T10:11:56.430Z] Worker failed to index functions
[2023-10-02T10:11:56.432Z] Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: BindingApi.cosmos_db_input() missing 1 required positional argument: 'connection'        
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 338, in _handle__functions_metadata_request
    fx_metadata_results = self.index_functions(function_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 607, in index_functions
    indexed_functions = loader.index_function_app(function_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 44, in call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 151, in index_function_app
    imported_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\gcookman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\gcookman\Code\KPMG-DAI-API\function_app.py", line 9, in <module>
    @app.cosmos_db_input(arg_name="documents",
```

Any help or guidance appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix of configs. `connection_string_setting` is for the old extension while `container_name` is for the new/current one.

Based on the error, you seem to tbe using the new one.

Change `connection_string_setting` to `connection`. The Function docs seem a bit off (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-python#configuration) because they don't have `_` but the names are the right ones.